# Cancel button near comment box

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, status-bydesign, comments

There is no cancel button near comment box ? To my surprise, I have to refresh the page if I withdraw while commenting on something.

Is it a bug raised ? If it is not, please consider this as a feature request.

Educate me, if I am missing something here :)

[image]

**Edit 1 :**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean *"cancel"*? Just... *don't* comment. They aren't saved like posts, so there's nothing to discard.

Comment: @jonrsharpe look at the edit and picture. When I'm editing tags, there is a `cancel` button. So now you are going to say 'just don't edit the tags' ? When I want to `just don't comment here, I want to close that box`. Right ?

Comment: The comment box does not need to be closed for the comment to be canceled -- just don't click the Add Comment button. Are you sure providing a link / button that only closes that box would add real value?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Exactly. That cancel button, just close the box, without adding the comment.

Comment: My point was that leaving the box open and not clicking the button has the exact same result. This is also true for the tag edition UI, except that UI has two modes (read and edit) and the cancel link allows to switch back to read mode. There is no such concept at play for the comment box.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Exactly my point, why exactly it is there from editing a comment ?  We can just leave just `save edits` button without clicking?

Comment: Because editing a comment brings back the two modes (read and edit), so the link provides a way to switch back to read mode. There is no read mode to switch back to for new comments (since they don't exist yet). Adding a cancel link would improve consistency indeed, but wouldn't achieve much more.

Comment: I had the same question. Once you cick on add-a-comment and then decide not to (say to answer instead) there is no way of closing the text-box that is now taking up space. If you are on mobile, it takes up about 20% of the screen and one has to ensure that they simply don't end up clicking on add-comment. If you are going to have a way of opening a box then it makes sense to allow users to close it too, the size of the close button being the same one as that of the 'Add Comment' button. Once opened, the box only adds to the clutter.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, the important difference between these two is that the *regular tags*, while not editing, are functional  useful  UI elements:

- they are hyperlinks
- they provide (via hover) additional context and options (subscription, etc) relating to the tag
- they have visual distinction to indicate a few things (mod-only tags, required tags, favorite tags, etc)

There is something *worth bringing back*.

---

In the case of comments; the only thing there is to "bring back" is the "add a comment" link; the purpose of which can only ever be: to display a UI that you already have available. The main reasons we don't show  the edit box immediately is to avoid clutter (under  every  post they add up), and to make it obvious to new users that they are adding a *comment* as opposed to an *answer*.

As such: it isn't *useful* to offer a cancel here. As such; this is by design. If you don't want to add a comment after all; just *don't add one*.